How do I disable all quest popups in Discord?
Occasionally Discord will show a popup for a sponsored Quest I can do in the bottom left corner. I can dismiss individual quests by hovering over the quest, clicking ..., and selecting "Hide This", but I want to get rid of quests entirely.
How do I disable all Quest notifications in Discord?


You can disable personalized quests in the settings. This should stop notifications from showing up. Go to Privacy and Safety -> In-game rewards.
You will still be able to find quests in the explore tab of Discord though if you want to accept any.

